# Using HOCs on Generic Typescript React Components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, redux-form

I have a React component which is typed with a generic. That component in turn is extended with a higher order component (in this case, redux-form). Here's a stripped back version of my class and the HOC being applied:

```
import * as React from "react";

interface MyFormProps<D> {
    prop: D;
    form: string;
}

class MyForm<D> extends React.Component<MyFormProps<D>, {}> {
    render(): JSX.Element {
        return (
            <form>
                {this.props.prop}
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export const ConnectedMyForm = reduxForm({} as Config<any, {}, {}>)(MyForm);
```

Then I try to create a typed version of my component in another component.

```
import { ConnectedMyForm } from "./my-form";

interface FormType {
    // Form props here
}

type TypedForm = new () => ConnectedMyForm<FormType>;
const TypedForm = ConnectedMyForm as TypedForm;
```

In order to be able to use it in TSX as follows:

```
<TypedForm />
```

This method works absolutely fine on another Component I've built which doesn't have HOC applied but here I get the following error:

> error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ConnectedMyForm'.

on the `type TypedForm = new () => ConnectedMyForm<FormType>;` line.

This only happens when I apply the HOC function to my component. I'm guessing it's because I've not specified the generic typing on the connected version of the form. But how would I specify that typing?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a `hoc/EnhancedForm` like:

```
import * as React from 'react';

interface EnhancedProps {
    name: string;
}

export default <T extends {}>(Component: React.StatelessComponent<T> | React.ComponentClass<T>):
    React.StatelessComponent<T & EnhancedProps> =>
    (props: T & EnhancedProps) => {
        return <Component { ...props } />
    }
```

And then just use that HoC in your `SimpleForm` like:

```
const SimpleForm = props => {

  const handleSubmit = () => { alert("Validated"); }

  const { pristine, reset, submitting } = props
  return (
    <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit }>
      <div>
        <label>First Name</label>
        ....
    </form>
  )
}

export default EnhancedForm(reduxForm({
  form: 'simple' // a unique identifier for this form
})(SimpleForm))
```

And finally use it as you describe:

```
render() {
    return (
      <SimpleForm name="SimpleName" />
    );
  }
```

Comment: I get what you're trying to do but I'm trying to give a generic type to one of the props of the form, not type the entire props object with a generic.

Basically, I'm trying to create a form that accepts a type as the type of the data that will be represented in the form. At the minute, it's just typed as `any`, which works, but it would be nice to have some proper typing on the form data.

Comment: Or maybe there's something I'm missing?